# HTML divs grid - unwanted space between rows

Tags: css, html, grid

I'm trying to build a simple grid of `div`s: ([live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/cSWnb/3/))

HTML:

```
<div class="board"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var boardHTML = '';

    for (var r = 0; r < 2; r++) {
        var row = '<div class="row">';

        for (var c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
            row += '<div class="cell"></div>';
        }

        row += '</div>';
        boardHTML += row;
    }

    $('.board').append(boardHTML);
});
```

CSS:

```
.cell {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
.row {
    background-color: red;
}
```

But, the result looks like this:

[image]

**QUESTION:** What causes this space between rows?

One possible solution is:

```
.row {
    height: 30px;
}
```

[image]

Also, to get rid of the extra space on the right hand side, I could add:

```
.board {
    width: 150px; /*   5 * 30px   */
}
```

[image]

However, I wonder if there is a better solution which doesn't require setting the width/height in pixels.

Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write like `vertical-align: top;` in your `.cell` CSS. Write like

```
.cell {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 30px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/cSWnb/6/

Comment: That's interesting. It works when width and height are 30px, but doesn't work if they are small enough, e.g. 10px: http://jsfiddle.net/cSWnb/9/

Comment: My second problem is to get rid of the red space at the right hand side without setting board's width in pixels.

Comment: write vertical-align:top & font-size:0; in .row CSS. Check  this http://jsfiddle.net/cSWnb/24/

Comment: `font-size:0` means that I can't put any text in the cells. I don't want make this assumption.

Comment: that's why i give his child font-size:15px;. write a text on it. It's make no problem to it.

Answer (score 0):

These settings are all behaving as expected so it's not clear exactly what you are hoping for.

Instead of setting the row height, you might instead play with the margins. Margins are what cause the space between block elements.

For the last item, try setting the width of the div to auto.

Comment: Try `div { margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; }`